# Creating jpeg image from base 64 encoded string

Tags: php, codeigniter, base64

I am using the following code to create an image from base64 encoded data

```
 $signature_image = time() . ".jpg";
 $fp = fopen('./uploads/customers/' . $signature_image, "w");
 fwrite($fp, base64_decode($this->input->post('signature_image')));
 fclose($fp);
```

But when I try to open the image I get following error

> Error interpreting JPEG image file (Unsupported marker type 0x60).

Can any assist me on the same

Thanks,

Comment: A common error is that PHP is outputting something just before the encoded data is decoded. Have you used enctype="multipart/form-data" on the form?

Comment: nope i have used x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: How do you attempt to read the file? By PHP? If yes, check that you are outputting the right headers for JPG and that there is no random output before the image is shown.